# How to stop a daemon from starting up on boot-up in Debian

Tags: debian, package-management

There's a few daemons I disable from starting on boot-up. As an example, I use the following:

```
 sudo update-rc.d -f postgresql remove
```

I'm not even sure if that command is correct and I don't remember where I got it from.

Anyways, whenever I upgrade **`postgresql`**, the setting is lost (i.e. the daemon starts up on reboot).

Comment: On Debian with SysVinit, I like [`file-rc`](http://packages.debian.org/sid/file-rc). Instead of managing symlinks, I manage a text file with my runlevel configurations.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`update-rc.d` was initially used by package upgrade scripts. `remove` is called on package uninstall and removes all links, `defaults` is called on package install, `enable` or `disable` might be used depending on debconf and are useful to sysadmins. The cleanups `remove` does are not in fact useful to disable a service. From the man page:

> A  common  system  administration error is to delete the links with the
>          thought that this will "disable" the service, i.e., that this will prevent
>          the  service from being started.  However, if all links have been
>          deleted then the next time  the  package  is  upgraded,  the  package's
>          postinst  script  will  run  update-rc.d  again and this will reinstall
>          links at their factory default locations.  The correct way  to  disable
>          services  is  to  configure  the service as stopped in all runlevels in
>          which it is started by default.  In the System V init system this means
>          renaming the service's symbolic links from S to K.

`sudo update-rc.d postgresql disable` will do what you want, because it keeps the rc.d symlinks but with the K (killed, stopped) prefix. Revert it with an `enable`. Some services support being disabled from their `/etc/defaults/$service` file, but sadly there are exceptions. Other ways to disable a service are to chmod -x the `/etc/init.d/$service` file, or to insert an `exit 0` at the top of it.

Answer (score 9):

To clarify the best solution, similar to the answer Tobu gave:

1. **Do not** use `update-rc.d` with the `remove` option.
2. Instead, use `update-rc.d` with the `disable` option.

Example: `update-rc.d postgresql disable`

---

PLUS, You can also find (and disable) other, more specific services with `systemctl`.

Example: `systemctl disable pppd-dns.service`

Comment: +1 for the advise to not use the REMOVE option

Answer (score 3):

Tobu is absolutely right, but for completeness there is a tool to give you a smart overview: `sysv-rc-conf`. For copy&patse:

```
apt-get install sysv-rc-conf
```

Running `sysv-rc-conf` you'll see which script is executed in which runlevel. You can enable/disable services via `space` and quit with `q`.

Comment: I also like `rcconf`, its in the standard repos.  Remember though none of these will work with upstart, which is default on Ubuntu.  Although plenty of stuff still uses the legacy init.