# Managing startup applications in debian buster 10 (mate)

Tags: debian, startup, mate-desktop, autostart

I saw [How to manage startup applications in Debian 9?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374012/how-to-manage-startup-applications-in-debian-9)

At that time, gnome-tweak-tool was the go-to-tool however, since a few days, that app. is not there anymore.

I am running on Debian buster.

https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gnome-tweak-tool. See the news section and specifically https://tracker.debian.org/news/931994

I even tried out a version from snapshot but it didn't do anything for couple of apps. which I wanted to be there right from boot.

I tried bum only to see and understand that it's a run-level editor, useful but not for the scenario I have in mind which is simply asking the system to start some services after logging on to the desktop. Even systemd-ui which was a separate package in no longer there.

So how can we do the same in mate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To figure out what happened to a package, you need to look at the removal reason from unstable, not testing. In [`gnome-tweak-tool`](https://tracker.debian.org/news/932637)’s case, this is given as “RoM; source package has been renamed to gnome-tweaks”, and true enough, there is now a [`gnome-tweaks`](https://packages.debian.org/source/testing/gnome-tweaks) source package, which builds a `gnome-tweaks` binary package and a `gnome-tweak-tool` transitional package.

The MATE equivalent is [`mate-tweak`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/mate-tweak). However in MATE, you configure your startup applications in the main control centre, using the “Startup Applications” applet.