# Why is minidlnad being started automatically and how to prevent its autostart?

Tags: debian, kde, autostart

Since recently `minidlnad` is starting automatically even though I haven't configured it to do so (I noticed that by running `sudo lsof -i` after startup).

How can I stop it from starting automatically? It does not show up in `bum` (Boot-Up Manager) [which currently seems to be the GUI to manage startup applications under GNU/Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374012/how-to-manage-startup-applications-in-debian-9).

It would also be useful to see why/how it was started after having killed the process with the process manager.

I'm using latest Debian 10 stable/KDE.

Comment: Have you tried disabling it with `systemctl`?

Answer (score 2):

To prevent it from starting automatically: `sudo systemctl stop minidlna.service && sudo systemctl disable minidlna.service`

I still would like to know why it's starting automatically even though I haven't configured it to do so and why it's not listed by `bum`.